# Add one identical column to next column respectively

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to add one duplicated column next to the existing column in my csv file. For example, a dataset looks like this.

```
A,B,C,D
D,E,F,G
```

Then to add one duplicated column.

```
A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D
D,D,E,E,F,F,G,G
```

Below is code I have tried but apparently it does not work.

```
import csv

with open('in.csv','r') as csvin:
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
        writer = csv.writer(csvout, lineterminator=',')
        reader = csv.reader(csvin, lineterminator=',')
        goal = []
        for line in reader:       
            for i in range(1,len(line)+1,2):
                line.append(line[i])
                goal.append(line)
        writer.writerows(goal)
```

Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do it succinctly as follows

```
from itertools import repeat
# open the file, create a reader
for row in reader:
    row_ = [i for item in row for i in itertools.repeat(item,2)]
# now do whatever you want to do with row_
```

Comment: @Sakura that is not a package. It's a _built-in_ module. You can repeat however many times as possible. Without it you can implement yourself, but I believe that will defeat the purpose of `itertools` that is tailor made for efficient iteration.

Comment: @Sakura Btw, the equivalent implementation of `repeat` is given in the docs for `itertools`. You can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
for i in range(0,len(line)):
     goal.append(i);
     goal.append(i);
```

not best implentation, but it should work